# SQL update query with substring WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, substring, where-clause

I have a table called citation and a table called sources. I want to create a foreign key called "source_id" in the citation table. Citation has a text field "link" where the url contains an ID at least 7 digits long, 22 characters from the end of the string. Sources has a big integer field "signature" that contains just that ID at least 7 digits long. I want to use this ID to create a foreign key for as many as possible. The IDs 8 digits long I will fix afterward, probably manually, as there should not be many.

When I use this select query, it returns 10 values only (I had set up 10 entries to match so I could test this), with the correct ID matching.

```
select s.signature, c.link, s.id, c.id
from citation c, sources s
where right(s.signature, 7) = substring (Reverse(c.link), 22, 7);
```

However, when I use this update query with the same where clause, it updates all records of "sources_id" in the citation table.

```
update citation
set source_id = s.id 
from citation c, sources s
where right(s.signature, 7) = substring (Reverse(link), 22, 7);
```

What am I missing? It should only update the 10 records with matching IDs within the WHERE clause substrings.

Comment: Do **not** repeat the target table of an UPDATE in the FROM clause.

Comment: @pringi: The link to a *MySQL* solution is misleading. Postgres has different (IMO better) syntax rules for `UPDATE`.

Comment: Yes, I got my answer, thank you! Leaving out the target table in the FROM clause did the trick. Also the hint that it is weird that the reverse should result in a match was helpful. In the end, I went with this:
update citation
set source_id = s.id
from sources s
where right(s.signature, 7) = Reverse (substring (Reverse(citation.link), 22, 7));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual about `UPDATE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6)

> Do not repeat the target table as a ***`from_item`*** unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the ***`from_item`***).

So:

```sql
UPDATE citation c
SET    source_id = s.id
FROM   sources s
WHERE  right(s.signature, 7) = substring(reverse(c.link), 22, 7);
```

It's odd that the substring matches as *reversed* string, and what you mention about 8 digits, but all of that seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: That's actually an illegal form of joined update and you will not find such an example anywhere in the MS documentation.  It'll also drive you nuts someday when a certain unpredictable set of circumstances occur and it pegs a bunch of CPUs and a 2 second query suddenly take more than 2 hours to execute.  The correct for is to use the target table in the FROM clause with an alias and the UPDATE would target the alias.

Comment: @JeffModen: Remarkable approach to recommend the "MS documentation" for a Postgres solution. No "illegal form" here, and your "correct form" makes no sense. Seems like you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Heh.  Gimme a minute to wash the egg off my face to thank you for the correction.  I totally missed that.