# UPDATE from another table with multiple WHERE criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join, dblink

In Postgres 9.5, I want to connect to another DB using Postgres' dblink, get data and then use them to update another table.

```
-- connect to another DB, get data from table, put it in a WITH 
WITH temp_table  AS 
( 
    SELECT r_id, descr,  p_id 
    FROM 
    dblink('myconnection', 
           'SELECT 
            r_id, descr,   p_id 
            FROM table
            WHERE table.p_id 
            IN (10,20);'
    ) 
    AS tempTable(r_id integer, descr text, p_id integer)
) 

-- now use temp_table  to update

UPDATE anothertable   
SET     
descr =temp_table.descr 
FROM anothertable    AS x
INNER JOIN temp_table 
ON  
x.r_id = temp_table.r_id 
AND 
x.p_id = temp_table.p_id 
AND 
x.p_id IN (2)  ;
```

dblink works fine and if I do `select * from temp_table`  before the `UPDATE`, it has data.

The issue is the `UPDATE` itself. It runs with no errors, but it never actually updates the table.

I tried changing the `UPDATE` to:

```
UPDATE anothertable   
SET     
descr =temp_table.descr 
FROM anothertable    AS x , temp_table
WHERE x.r_id = temp_table.r_id 
AND 
x.p_id = temp_table.p_id 
AND 
x.p_id IN (2)  ;
```

Same as above: runs with no errors, but it never actually updates the table.

I also tried to change the `UPDATE` to:

```
UPDATE anothertable   
INNER JOIN temp_table
ON x.r_id = temp_table.r_id 
    AND 
    x.p_id = temp_table.p_id 
    AND 
    x.p_id IN (2) 
    SET descr =temp_table.descr
```

But I get:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER" SQL state: 42601
> Character: 1894

How can I fix this to actually update?

Comment: Aside: Postgres 9.5 has reached EOL in 2021. Consider upgrading to a current version! https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 2):

Don't repeat the target table in the `FROM` clause of the `UPDATE`:

```sql
WITH temp_table AS ( ... )

UPDATE anothertable x
SET    descr = t.descr 
FROM   temp_table t
WHERE  x.r_id = t.r_id 
AND    x.p_id = t.p_id 
AND    x.p_id IN (2);
```

Or simplified:

```sql
...
AND    x.p_id = 2
AND    t.p_id = 2
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6)

> Do not repeat the target table as a ***`from_item`*** unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the ***`from_item`***).

Related:

- [UPDATE statement with multiple joins in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386246/update-statement-with-multiple-joins-in-postgresql/32386537#32386537)
- [SQL update query with substring WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295978/sql-update-query-with-substring-where-clause/71302018#71302018)